# Can you return multiple COUNTs in one SQL statement?

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Java and SQL, and I'm trying to count all the goats in a petting zoo.  I know that I can use the following query:

```
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT'
```

Simple enough.  Now, let's say goats come in one of three colors: brown, black, or grey.  If I want to count the number of each color, I can execute the following queries:

```
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT' AND
       pz.animalType.color = 'BROWN'

  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT' AND
       pz.animalType.color = 'BLACK'

  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT' AND
       pz.animalType.color = 'GREY'
```

This method works, but it's slow.  Doing this opens the table four times: once to get the total count, and 3 more times for the individual colors.   **Is there any way to return all four colors in *one* query?**

**EDIT:**  For clarity, let's say there are 15 goats.  Nine are brown, 0 are black, and 6 are grey.  The first query would return 15.  The second would return 9.  The third and last queries would return 0 and 6, respectively. I'm looking for one which returns all four values at once (so I'm not reading the same table four different times).  Possibly an array? { 15, 9, 0, 6 }

Comment: You mean something like 'GOAT' AND color in ('BROWN' ,'BLACK', 'GREY')?

Comment: Do you want distinct values, as in - a value for brown, a value for black, and a value for gray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT SUM(case when pz.animalType.color = 'BROWN' then 1 else 0 end) as browns,
         SUM(case when pz.animalType.color = 'BLACK' then 1 else 0 end) as blacks,
         SUM(case when pz.animalType.color = 'GREY'  then 1 else 0 end) as greys ,
         COUNT(1) as total
  FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT' AND
         (
           pz.animalType.color = 'BROWN' or 
           pz.animalType.color = 'BLACK' or 
           pz.animalType.color = 'GREY'
         )
  WHERE pz.animalType is not null
```

Comment: This is good but I feel like UNION ALL could be faster if indexes are used.

Comment: Does oracle optimize union's multiple selects into  a single sweep? But ofcourse case whens will be gone.

Comment: question about the AND clause: do I need it if those 3 colors are the only choices, and not null?

Comment: if all are non-null goats, its ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the counts in one query using group by:

```
SELECT 
      pz.animalType.color, COUNT(*)
FROM PettingZoo pz
WHERE pz.animalType = 'GOAT'
GROUP BY pz.animalType.color
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Kevin forgot the the *group by* clause:

```
SELECT pz.animalType.color, COUNT(*) FROM PettingZoo pz WHERE
pz.animalType = 'GOAT' GROUP BY pz.animalType.color;
```